# phpmyadmin - cannot login with password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Within Phpmyadmin (in Xampp) I copied/duplicated the 3 root users (@localhost, @127.0.0.1 and ::1) and gave this new user(s) an identical name and password.

I also changed the PhpMyAdmin config.inc.php to the new username and password.

BUT:
**Logging in with those new user only works when I leave the password EMPTY!** (Like it does with the root user).

Why?

Why does it FAIL when I use the users correct password, but WORKS when I leave the password empty. Isn't this crazy?

Comment: Did you reload user premissions? Can be done via phpMyAdmin (Permissions->Flush priviliges) or by issung this sql command: FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;

Comment: @maxhb: Yes! But it still does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to phpMyAdmin > User accounts > edit privileges (for the required user) > change password (from the top menu)
There will be two radio buttons (No Password & Password).
choose password and save. 
See if that would solve the issue.